# General guide for securing windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, hardening

Is there a guide for securing windows server 2008?  I seem to remember reading a MS doc on how to harden a Win2k server, but I can not find a publication for win2k8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft's [Windows Server 2008 Security Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=fb8b981f-227c-4af6-a44b-b115696a80ac&displaylang=en)  has been replaced by the [Windows Server 2008 Security Compliance Management Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc514539.aspx).

Comment: +1 Thanks.  I'm installing it right now.  I was really hoping MS would provide a document, the software seems very overkill, esp b/c I have to install SQL Server Express...which seems like it increases my attack surface.

Answer (score 1):

@CLJ, sorry to post this as an answer, it is meant to be a comment on your comment but I can't see how to do that!
You are not meant to install the Security Compliance Management Toolkit on the server, rather on some other computer/technician station or virtual machine. It is basically a tool that gives you group policy settings to apply to your domain. You definitely shouldn't be installing it on a production server.

Comment: Good point, I just learned that myself.